# How can I make sure Users Enter a Number not a String?

Tags: ruby

I expect the user to enter a Number. In case users enter a char I want to throw a error.

I tried to parse the values.

```
def pruefeZeitbudget(eingabeZeitaufwand)
    @validierungsWert = eingabeZeitaufwand.to_f
    loop do
      if @validierungsWert > 24
        puts 'Wert überschreitet das Tagesmaximum von 24 Stunden. Erneute Eingabe!'
        @validierungsWert = gets.chomp.to_f
      else
        puts 'Eingabe okay.'
        break
      end
    end
```

Comment: I don’t think the title is quite what you mean, as users can enter nothing other than strings. Perhaps you want users to be required to enter the string representation of a number, in which case you should indicate whether it should be an integer, a non-negative integer, a float or something else. btw, `gets.chomp.to_f` can be written `gets.to_f`, for the same reason that `1.23cats.to_f #=> 1.23`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Float(eingabeZeitaufwand)` . It will raise error if the input is invalid Float type. Otherwise, it returns float value.

The complete code should like

```
def pruefeZeitbudget
  begin 
    @validierungsWert = Float(gets.chomp)
    loop do
      if @validierungsWert > 24
        puts 'Wert überschreitet das Tagesmaximum von 24 Stunden. Erneute Eingabe!'
      else
        puts 'Eingabe okay.'
        break
      end
    end
  rescue
    puts "Invalid input"
  end
end
```

Comment: Ummmm... `gets.chomp.to_f` is still present on Line 7. Also I am not sure if the OP considers `"1.2e1"` as "entering a character" but the `Float` method will accept e notation

Comment: I updated the code. So the `@validierungsWert` variable should be get from user input? it's great that `Float()` can do a lot of things like that. Haha. Hope that my answer's useful

Comment: you can drop the begin;end the rescue will work regardless

Comment: you use rescue and ensure just like in a begin;end block
found this http://seejohncode.com/2012/04/17/short-tip-rescuing-a-method-in-ruby/
also, most consider it bad to catch a general error, but that would go too far for an simple example as yours (most wouldn't even use a rescue here)

Answer (score 1):

Strings result in 0.0 when you run them through .to_f, so adding an or statement that requires the number to be more than 1 should make sure that no strings are entered.

```
def pruefeZeitbudget(eingabeZeitaufwand)
    @validierungsWert = eingabeZeitaufwand.to_f
    loop do
      if @validierungsWert > 24 or @validierungsWert < 1 
        puts 'Wert überschreitet das Tagesmaximum von 24 Stunden. Erneute Eingabe!'
        @validierungsWert = gets.chomp.to_f
      else
        puts 'Eingabe okay.'
        break
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: As [@CarySwoveland pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551620/how-can-i-make-sure-users-enter-a-number-not-a-string#comment99685207_56551620) `"1.23cats".to_f #=> 1.23` so just checking if it evaluates to more than 1 is insufficient.